# Excel/Google Spreadsheet LOOKUPIF / MATCHIF / Cell as range?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following Google Spreadsheet table:

```
                                 A        B       C        D
1   Users                       1-30    31-80   81-150  151-500
2   Discount %                   0%       1%      2%       3%
3   License user / month        $10   $9       $8        $7
```

I would like the following to be calculated:

```
 20    50    90
$200  $450  $720
```

Because **20** is between **1-30** so it calculates as `20*$10=200`

And **50** is between **31-80** so it calculates as `50*$8=450`

So basically I need cell `A1` to be as a range/series of numbers and I want to that the formula will know to look at a *"range of ranges"* **A1:D1** and consider each cell **if <= 30** maybe or something that way.

I tried **LOOKUP** / **MATCH** but couldn't find anything that is generic enough without putting a lot of IFs in the formula.

Comment: Change your first row to only the minimum. `1,31,81...` then use hlookup with the forth criterion as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following sample image, change the cell number format in C2:F2 to:

```
0-3\0    ◄ C2 custom number format
0-8\0    ◄ D2 custom number format
0-15\0   ◄ E2 custom number format
0-5\0\0  ◄ F2 custom number format
```

Note that the zeroes have been 'escaped' with a backslash to avoid confusion with reserved format mask characters.

Input 1, 31, 81 and 151 into C2:F2.

[image: cnf_range]

All that remains is a simple [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) and some maths. In H4 as,

```
=H3*HLOOKUP(H3, $C2:$F4, 3, TRUE)
```

Fill right as necessary.

[image: cnf_range_formula]

Comment: There is a way without creating a 'custom number format' for each cell? maybe one that can fit all?

Comment: Sure, you could create an array formula that does an awful lot of work for very few results but I prefer not to proselytize bad practises or bad worksheet design.

Comment: I think it might fit more to my needs, because the ranges might change more often than the amount of cells I calculate on

Comment: Then write a Worksheet_Change event macro for the intersect of Target and D2:F2 that takes any value typed in and rewrites the custom number format to the left.